# Unable to use npm request package to meteor app

Tags: meteor, npm

I executed `meteor npm install --save request` in the command line

I imported the request library in my code `import {request} from 'request'`

And tried to use it with

```
request('http://www.google.com', function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
      console.log(body) // Show the HTML for the Google homepage.
    }
})
```

However I keep on getting the following error:

`undefined is not a function`

How do I use the npm `request` package with my meteor app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default export from the request package is the object you are looking for. Change your import statement to the following:

```js
import request from 'request';
```

It may be that you need the low-level functionality from `request`, however your example could also be accomplished with meteor's [HTTP pacakge](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/http) (which is itself a wrapper around `request`).

Here's an example:

```js
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { HTTP } from 'meteor/http';

Meteor.startup(() => {
  const resp = HTTP.get('http://www.google.com');
  console.log(resp.content);
});
```

Note you'll need to run `meteor add http` for that to work.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Clearly I misunderstood the use of {} when importing. Regarding Meteor's http package, I find it a bit hard to use especially if my url points to an image. `resp.content` seems to be a string .